# Adding repeating line numbers

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with about 10k lines. I would like to add the line numbers to the first column, but in a way to repeat the line numbers 1-100. For example,

```
1 12313
2 3434
.
.
.
100 4233
1 24523
.
.
.
100 4543543
1
.
.
.     
100
```

How could I do it using grep or awk? I managed to print the line numbers, but without repeating using awk

```
awk '{ print NR, $1 }' p2.dat > p3.dat
```

Comment: Is the goal to add 12313 to the first 100 lines, and 3434 to second 100?  Or 1 to the first 100 lines, and 2 to second 100?

Comment: 1 to the first 100 lines, 2 to the second 100 lines, and so on. I managed to do it with: awk '{ for (k = 1; k <= 100; k++) if (100*(k-1) < NR && NR <= 100*k) print k, $1 }' p2.dat > p3.dat

Comment: @ilkkachu, well we both agree that's not so good.  However, this may not be not so much a matter of modification as clarification.  Here the OP had a few difficulties putting a spec into words...

Comment: @user5694985, Thanks for the clarification.  Looking at that the output of your `awk` code, it seems you wanted to _prefix_ or _prepend_ line numbers in incremented groups, not _add_ numbers to input data.

Comment: **Rolled this back to the version that matches accepted answer**.   Please start a new question for the new requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo (remainder) operator `%` on `NR`. `NR % 100` would give 1,2,3...99,0,1,2..., so it needs a bit of tweaking. This should do:

```
awk '{ print (NR-1) % 100 + 1, $1 }' p2.dat > p3.dat
```

This, of course is an answer to the [original question,](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/315882/3) not the modified one.

Comment: And what if want to add line number 1 to the first 100 lines, and number 2 to the second 100 lines and so on up to line number 100?

Comment: @user5694985, from that spec, it's unclear which numbers are to be added.  That is if the input file was the output of `seq 77 10077`, did you wish for the first line of output to be `1:78` or `1:154` or something else?  Please elaborate.

Comment: I would like to add number 1 to the first 100 lines, number 2 to the second 100 lines, and so on:

Comment: I would like to add number 1 to the first 100 lines, number 2 to the second 100 lines, and so on:

Comment: @agc, The way I read the question, I understood the purpose was to just add the line numbers as a new field in the front of the line. Not anything having to do with numerical addition of the values.

Comment: Rolled question back to most recent version that matches accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with a minimum of looping:

```
awk '{ printf("%0.0f ",(NR/100.001)+.5) ;print $1 }' p2.dat > p3.dat
```

Demo, print the first *10* numbers, and in groups of *3* prefix an increment:

```
seq 10 | awk '{ printf("%0.0f ",(NR/3.001)+.5) ;print $1 }'
```

Output:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 7
3 8
3 9
4 10
```

---

Note: `awk` rounding shows some binary conversion glitches.  The above code uses expressions like `(NR/3.001)+.5)`, when it would be clearer to write `(NR/3)+.5)` or even `(NR*(1/3))+.5)`.  Unfortunately those don't work:

```
# WRONG: (rounding errors), shows four '2's, etc.
seq 10  | awk '{ printf("%0.0f ",(NR/3)+.5) ;print $1 }' 
1 1
1 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 7
3 8
4 9
4 10
```